# How ArcMap calculates area of polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, area

I am working on a project to compare between calculating the area of ​​a polygon using Google Earth Pro and using ArcMap 10.8, and the methods used by the programs for that.

How does ArcMap 10.8 calculate the area of a polygon?

Comment: Please decide which of Google Earth Pro or ArcGIS Pro (or whichever ArcGIS product you're using) you wish to ask about in this particular question.  That way you describe what you've tried/researched prior to asking here.

Comment: I think the answer is "the usual way". There are several different algorithms available in the `arcpy.Polygon.getArea()` method, so you'd need to specify which one you are using.

Comment: I remember a question like this from a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451426/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-2d-polygon and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492407/area-of-an-irregular-polygon It's the sum of the cross product of all the segments; OGC convention holds that exterior rings are clockwise and interior rings are counter-clockwise, therefore exterior rings will have a positive sum and interior rings (islands) have a negative sum. Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAyPIMme3Yw

Comment: I collected GPS points around my city and imported them into ArcMap, where I converted them from points to a line and then to a polygon. Next, I calculated the area using the attribute table. How does the program calculate the area of this irregular polygon?